# Kivy Label text not updating - only updates at the last change in the method

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, label

*Using Kivy 1.11.1 and Python 3.7.6.*

I have this peculiar problem and I couldn't find to answer anywhere.

I want to update Label's text (here: `status` Label) in a method **twice** in the method that is called on the button press (in this example, `display_hello_status()`. But it seems Kivy updates the interface only **after** the method call is finished - causing only the latest change to the Label's text to be rendered.

Below you can find the code with the problematic method.

**main.py:**

```py
import time

import kivy
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.app import App

kivy.require('1.11.1')


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class PrintHello(Screen):
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    status = ObjectProperty(None)

    def display_hello_status(self):
        # Inform about process of generating hello text.
        self.status.text = "printing hello..."  # this text is never displayed.
        # Pretend something is happening in the background.
        time.sleep(2)
        self.username.text = f"Hello, {self.username.text}!"
        # Display information indicating successful printing.
        self.status.text = "printed!"


class MyApp(App):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**my.kv:**

```
WindowManager:
    PrintHello:

<PrintHello>:
    username: username_text_input
    status: status_label

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            padding: 8
            spacing: 8

            Label:
                text: "Your name:"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 32
                bold: True

            TextInput:
                id: username_text_input
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 32
                multiline: False

        FloatLayout:

            Button:
                text: "Print"
                size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.6, "y": 0.4}
                on_release: root.display_hello_status()

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.2, "y": 0.4}
                padding: 4

                Label:
                    text: "Status:"
                    bold: True

                Label:
                    id: status_label
                    text: "off"
                    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0  # black
                    color: 1, 1, 1, 1  # white
```

So what I want to achieve is:

1. Inform user through text and color change that some process is undergoing.
2. Do some process in the background, which takes some time (simulated by `time.sleep(2)`.
3. Display the information that the program successfully completed the process.

The question is: how do I do that? How do I force a Widget (Label in this case) to update in the middle of the method?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnAnderson I implemented a standalone version of the problem as suggested. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that as long as you have a method running on the main thread, as your `display_hello_status()` is, kivy is unable to update the GUI. So, when the `display_hello_status()` method runs, changes are made to the `username` and `status` widgets, but those changes cannot be displayed by kivy until it gets a chance to run on the main thread. By the time kivy get the main thread back, the first changes have already been changed again, so only the final changes get displayed.

The fix is to return from the `display_hello_status()` method quickly, allowing kivy to reflect the changes you made. The `background` something can actually be run in the background using a `Thread`. Then that `Thread` can schedule another GUI update on the main thread.

Generally, you should avoid doing lengthy processing on the main thread. Anything that runs as a result of an event (like a button press) will run on the main thread. So doing that processing on another thread (or in some cases even another process) allows kivy to keep the GUI up to date and responsive. Along with that, any changes that you make to the GUI, should be done on the main thread. That is where `Clock.schedule_once()` comes in handy.

Here is a modified version of your `PrintHello` class that follows the above suggestions:

```
class PrintHello(Screen):
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    status = ObjectProperty(None)

    def display_hello_status(self):
        # Inform about process of generating hello text.
        self.status.text = "printing hello..."  # this text is never displayed.
        # Pretend something is happening in the background. Actually make it happen on a background thread
        threading.Thread(target=self.do_somehing).start()

    def do_somehing(self):
        print('starting something')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('finished something')
        
        # schedule the GUI update back on the main thread
        Clock.schedule_once(self.something_finished)

    def something_finished(self, dt):
        self.username.text = f"Hello, {self.username.text}!"
        # Display information indicating successful printing.
        self.status.text = "printed!"
```